# Ubuntu: Dynamics are not working after suspending system

Tags: dynamic, ubuntu

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit and I'm running *Mathematica* 10.1. Usually, I don't turn my computer completely off but I'm using the **Suspend** function which is AFAIK a *suspend to RAM*.

After waking the computer, everything is normal except that I cannot use any dynamic content inside *Mathematica*. Specifically, this means I see e.g. `Manipulate` regions normally, but I cannot move any slider. Let me clear this further. For this simple example

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

- I cannot move the slider `a`
- I can press the `+` signs and the slider controls open. There

  - I can input a value manually and it is applied to the graphic
  - I cannot press any buttons, although the buttons are highlighted when I move the mouse over them.
- I can "hide the controls" on the `+` sign in the very top right corner and all other things like "Autorun" seems to work too.

  - During the autorun, I can pause the animation but I'm not able to start it again. The "close" button works. All other buttons don't.

The problem is fixed by restarting *Mathematica* (a Kernel quit is not enough).

The question is: Does someone have the same problem? Is it possible to fix this problem?