# Mathematica closes on suspend in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've noticed this issue in Mathematica 8 and 10 on my laptop which runs Ubuntu 14.04. If I've recently saved the notebook, it will close just before my laptop completes the suspend. If I haven't saved, the "Save changes to 'notebook.nb' before quitting?" dialog box shows up and Mathematica is still open when I resume from the suspend. This happens everytime.

An easy work around is to add a trivial edit to the notebook so there is still some unsaved work when I suspend, but I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and found a solution? (Sometimes I forget to not save my work and lose the data I had in the kernel session...)

Also, I imagine this issue is related to 
[this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/manipulate-slider-unresponsive-after-suspend-in-linux) 
as well as 
[this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86505/ubuntu-dynamics-are-not-working-after-suspending-system)
which I also experience on my laptop but neither of which seem to have been resolved yet.
Mathematica appears to have some issues running during a suspend cyle.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to Wolfram Support? They might be able to troubleshoot more thoroughly.